# How do I remove the iCloud symbol when trying to download an app?

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore, iphone

I've searched and found the Find My iPhone app in the App Store. However, I can't download it as there is an iCloud Symbol and I can't get rid of it. How do I get the desired app on my iPhone 6?

Answer (score 2):

Tap the cloud to download. The iCloud symbol just means you can download the app from your purchase history.